# Parameter Estimation for Naive Bayes - Maximum a posteriori and Maximum Likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, naive-bayes, posterior, bayes

I am wondering if I understand those terms correctly. To summarize my thoughts:

In naive Bayes, our decision rule is basically the Maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimate of our hypothesis. We assign an observation $\pmb x$ to the class $\omega_j$ that has the largest posterior probability:

\begin{equation} \underset{j = 1 ..., m} {\mathrm{argmax}} \; P(\omega_{j} \mid \pmb x)   \end{equation}

This is called MAP since we are incorporating prior knowledge (the prior probabilities) to calculate the posterior probability:

\begin{equation} P(\omega_j \mid \pmb x_i) = \frac{P(\pmb x_i \mid \omega_j) \cdot P(\omega_j)}{P(\pmb x_i)} \end{equation}

where

- *$i$ = 1, 2, ..., n* (samples)
- *$j$ = 1, 2, ..., m* (class labels)
- $\omega_j$ = class $j$
- $\pmb x_i$ = features of sample $i$

Now, if we use the training data to estimate the parameters for the priors $P(\omega_j)$ based on the the frequency of the classes in the training data, this would be a Maximum Likelihood Estimate (MLE). 
Similarly, we can use MLE to calculate the class conditional probabilities $P(\pmb x_i \mid \omega_j)$ under the conditional independence assumption

\begin{equation} P(\pmb x \mid \omega_j) = \prod_{k=1}^{d} P(\pmb x_k \mid \omega_j) \end{equation}

Does this make sense at all?

Comment: If you use the training data to estimate the parameters for the priors, then that is a maxmimum likelihood estimate, only if it is based on maximising some likelihood. A related topic is that of maximum marginal likelihood in empirical Bayes, where you estimate the hyperparameters (parameters in the prior) by integrating out the model parameters, and then maximising the resulting marginal likelihood.